# How to debug from addresses mentioned in backtrace of gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f0412571733 in boost::detail::interruption_checker::~interruption_checker() ()
from /opt/HYDRAstor/objectStorage/lib/release_prod_64/libXyzService.so
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install python-2.6.6-52.x86_64
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007f0412571733 in boost::detail::interruption_checker::~interruption_checker() ()

from /opt/HYDRAstor/objectStorage/lib/release_prod_64/libXyzService.so
#1  0x00007f041181547a in boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::ptime const&) () from /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.1.41.0

#2  0x00007f040c5ea36c in void boost::this_thread::sleep<boost::posix_time::seconds>(boost::posix_time::seconds const&) ()
from /opt/HYDRAstor/objectStorage/lib/release_prod_64/libAbcLib.so

#3  0x00007f040c5daf63 in healthMonitoring::healthMonitoringController::print(bool) ()
from /opt/HYDRAstor/objectStorage/lib/release_prod_64/libAbcLib.so

#4  0x00007f0411813d10 in thread_proxy () from /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.1.41.0

#5  0x000000365d6079d1 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0

#6  0x000000365cee88fd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

(gdb)
```

As you can see from this backtrace, seg fault is raised by loaded shared library libXyz.so. So how can I know from what point in code of this shared library, this seg fault was raised?

What is the use of addresses mentioned in start of each frame. 
Please let me know if any more detail is needed.

Comment: "Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install python-2.6.6-52.x86_64"

Comment: Are you sure the problem is actually in that library? You don't pass a null pointer to a function not expecting a null pointer, or something similar?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes the problem is in that library. What I could depict at current point is that somewhere interrupt is raised, and since I have used boost sleep ion library, so they have been hit in library but not handled so seg fault. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> So how can I know from what point in code of this shared library, this
>   seg fault was raised?

Try to rebuild everything from scratch with optimizations disabled (with `-O0` or `-Og`) and with debug info enabled (`-g`). And make sure that you are not stripping resulting binaries (not running `strip` on them).

This should give you more meaningful stack traces with line numbers and file names.